# After filtering, check if array is not empty after filtering or has all original values; like Javascript's some() and every()

Tags: php, arrays, functional-programming, is-empty

JavaScript has the concept of array checker functions `some` and `every`, basically checking if a condition applies to either at least one or all elements of an array.

```
function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
  return element > 10;
}

[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10);  // false
[12, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10); // true
```

Is there an equivalent way for php?

Comment: `some()` would be the opposite of checking if the filtered array is empty.  `every()` would be checking if the original array was identical to the filtered array.  These are two, individual, well-covered tasks on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember: programming isn't magic. Different languages offer different native features/functionality, but that doesn't always mean you're stuck when you find your language is "missing" something.

Taking on the challenge of implementing these things on your own can be fun and rewarding.

```js
function array_any(callable $f, array $xs) {
  foreach ($xs as $x)
    if (call_user_func($f, $x) === true)
      return true;
  return false; 
}

function array_all(callable $f, array $xs) {
  foreach ($xs as $x)
    if (call_user_func($f, $x) === false)
      return false;
  return true; 
}
```

Now you can use them like you'd expect

```
echo (int) array_any(function($x) { return $x > 5; }, [1,2,3]); // 0
echo (int) array_any(function($x) { return $x > 5; }, [1,9,3]); // 1

echo (int) array_all(function($x) { return $x > 5; }, [5,6,7]);  // 0
echo (int) array_all(function($x) { return $x > 5; }, [6,7,8]);  // 1
```

@ggorlen suggests switching on [truthy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) values provided by the callback. All values in PHP are considered **true** except the following:

| type | value |
| --- | --- |
| boolean | false |
| int | 0 |
| float | 0.0 and -0.0 |
| string | "" |
| array | [], empty array |
| null | null |
| object | [overloaded objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) |

Watch out for `NAN`, it is considered `true`.

```js
function array_any(callable $f, array $xs) {
  foreach ($xs as $x)
    if (call_user_func($f, $x) == true) // truthy
      return true;
  return false; 
}

function array_all(callable $f, array $xs) {
  foreach ($xs as $x)
    if (call_user_func($f, $x) == false) // truthy
      return false;
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: Touché. Sometimes I think of those building blocks of a a language as magic words and not something that I could conjure myself.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be: `call_user_func($f, $x)` or `$f($x);`?

Comment: @k0pernikus yes to your last comment. Made a wups there !

Comment: Pretty good because it has early bailout and lets you provide a predicate, but hardcoding `=== true` and `=== false` prevents me from upvoting. I'd prefer relying on truthy and falsey values which better approximate `some`/`all` semantics.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks i made an update with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a native implemenation for these collection function. There are certain functional libraries out there, one is [phunctional](https://github.com/Lambdish/phunctional/blob/master/docs/docs.md) that supports `some` and `all`, e.g.:

```
use function Lambdish\Phunctional\some;

return some(
    function ($number) {
        return $number > 10;
    }, 
    [1, 4, 3, 9, 5]
);

// false
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP method some doesn't exist, but you can do something like this:

```
<?php
function isSomeBiggerThan10($numbers){
    foreach($numbers as $num){
        if($num > 10)
            return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

isSomeBiggerThan10([2, 5, 8, 1, 4]); //false
isSomeBiggerThan10([12, 5, 8, 1, 4]); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this (as in your example):

```
function isBiggerThan10($value) {
  return $value >= 10;
}
echo array_filter([2, 5,8, 1, 4], "isBiggerThan10") ? 'yes' : 'no';  
echo "<br>";
echo array_filter([12, 5, 8, 1, 4], "isBiggerThan10") ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: This visits every element. `some`/`any` semantics feature early bailout, so `array_filter` is inappropriate.